# Is it a good idea to change pre c++11 setting functions to modern templated ones with forwarding

Tags: c++, c++11

in, my classes I have lots of setXXX function which looks something like follows:

```
void setName(const std::string& newName) {
   name = newName;
}
```

this is what most programmers would do before C++11.

I learned (item 25 from Effective Moderm C++) that using forwarding would make those functions more efficient. So they would look as follows:

```
template<typename T>
void setName(T&& newName) {
   name = std::forward<T>(newName);
}
```

my qestion is whether it is a good idea to convert all such pre C++11 setting functions to  templates with forwarding reference parameter? My current understanding is that it will always be beneficial, at least I dont see drawbacks.

Comment: What about making the members public and access them directly? I don't see what all those set functions have to say.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia That is not always the good idea. What if the members should be set only? Makign them public means someone can read them and it could be the bad design.

Comment: I try to avoid getters and setters because they often break encapsulation. However I would say only do this if you identified a performance problem and only if you demonstrate this will actually give you better performance. Whenever you touch code you introduce bugs so make sure it is worth it. If it 'aint broke, don't fix it.

Comment: You can also ask yourself if you use the set function so extremely often that the difference will be noticeable. Otherwise, why change?

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia: It depends somewhat on how the function is documented and if it's part of a public API. If it says, for example, *"the behaviour is undefined if newName is empty"*, then using a setter function can be justified because it gives you the liberty of adding an assertion or an exception later on. If, however, there is no such contract at all and the function has already been exposed as-is to the public, then the setter is indeed just well-intentioned over-engineering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfect forwarding might sound interesting, though, I haven't used it for setters. (Although, I do work on performance critical software)

From my experience, I would say that it makes your code more complex to understand without much benefits. Let me explain:

### Complexity

Every caller of this set-method from now on, needs to check the type of the member before knowing what to pass. Let's assume a method 'setFile':

```
template<typename T>
void setFile(T &&file) { m_file = std::forward<T>(file); }
```

Should we call this method with a string (the filename), a c-style file-handle, a file-stream, your library specific file-wrapper ...? From seeing this method, it is not clear which to use. Especially not if you are new to the codebase.

Even though you class could be that small it can fit on a single terminal screen, code completion can't provide you with the information that you need.

Please note that compilation errors also become more complex if you use the wrong type.

### Gain

This brings us to the question: What do you gain? From now on, you use perfect forwarding. In other words, you can assign a `const char *` to a `std::string` without the performance overhead. However, how much will this gain? If you had performance critical code, this overload already exists. However, if the code is not performance critical, it won't matter that you loose a few CPU cycles.

On top of that, your compiler (Clang, GCC, MSVC ...) is an optimizing compiler. In other words, it allows you to write the code you want without having to worry about performance. (Don't get me wrong, if the code is critical, please worry, though trust the many compiler writers and researchers to handle the obvious)

So, if you have this `setName(const std::string &)`, make sure it is implemented in the header so that the compiler can reason about it and can try to optimize it away as much as possible. (For your own classes, make sure all constructors, destructor and assign/cast functions are visible to the compiler)

### Conclusion

I doubt it is useful to spend your time 'upgrading' your code. If it would bring that much gain, a clang-based utility would already exist. I would even bet that you would gain more performance by spending the same time profiling your application and fixing the low-hanging fruit.